# Changing Rstudio appearance

Tags: rstudio

For some reason, I would like to change my Rstido appearance as in the picture below. Like on the right-hand side **black** and lift side **white**. Any has a clue please share with me. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Tools > Global options > Appearance > Cobalt for editor theme, probably Classic for RStudio theme

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming, but about RStudio settings

Comment: @duckmayr I would think that the question is appropriate for the `rstudio` tag since the purpose of that tag is for questions that are specifically about RStudio as an IDE. It definitely isn't about R programming, so I will remove the `r` tag.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks for the clarification; I am retracting my close vote. I hadn't really encountered a question like this on the site before, but a closer inspection of [what is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) reveals that questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are fair game. My apologies, I thought this question would have been considered off-topic

Comment: @duckmayr You were half right. It is off-topic if put on the `r` tag.